# DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory was explicitly disabled from this updateRequestProcessorChain

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

I am using SOLR Cloud 6.0 with below setup,

3 physical VM, 5 collections with 6 shrad each with replication factor 2

I am running zookeeper on each VM

I am receiving below exception very frequently in solr logs,

```
o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RunUpdateProcessor has received an AddUpdateCommand containing a document that appears to still contain Atomic document update operations, most likely because DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory was explicitly disabled from this updateRequestProcessorChain
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:63)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:335)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
```

Can you please help me with the root cause ? Below is the snapshot of solrconfig,

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
    <!-- UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory will generate an id if none is present in the incoming document -->
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" />

    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
   <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.]</str>
      <str name="replacement">_</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <arr name="format">
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd</str>
      </arr>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
        <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
      </lst>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Regards,
Pratik Thaker

Comment: Can anyone please provide their suggestion ?